# Using CultureInfo in order to replace USD symbol with -

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

I am currently using this code in order to **remove** the `US symbol` and make the number appear as a **negative**

The code that I am using is:

```cs
public strNegative = "-";

string Result = TrnAmount
  .ToString("C3", new CultureInfo("en-US"))
  .Replace("$", strNegative);
```

However the result is appearing **with brackets**:

> Result = `"(-5)"`

When required format is

> Result = `"-5"`

Comment: The format string "C3" is asking the string formatting function to display the value as a currency. Why are you using it if you don't want a $ symbol? Also why are you mixing sign indicator and currency symbols?

Comment: Because I need the number to appear as -5.000 . I am using it this was as I am dealing with different currencies.

Comment: Just use `ToString("N3")` if you want 3 decimal places without currency unit.

Comment: What does that have to do with currencies? The number -5 can be displayed as "-5.000" using TrnAmount.ToString("0.000"), that has nothing to do with currency

Comment: Clone a [`NumberFormatInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo) and adjust the currency properties (if this really is a currency)

Answer (score 4):

Welcome. To get negative number just multiply number by -1. Then use [N3 as a string format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-numeric-n-format-specifier) if you want to get general number and not a currency format.

```
float TrnAmount = 2.5684155f;
string result = (-1 * TrnAmount).ToString("N3");
Console.WriteLine(result); //This will give you -2.568 as a result
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can create you own `CultureInfo`, e.g.

```
  // Same as US
  CultureInfo myUSCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);

  // Except dollar sign removed
  myUSCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "";
  // and negative pattern changed: "-value" instead of "(value)"
  myUSCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;
```

Then use it:

```
  decimal TrnAmount = -123456789.987M;

  Console.WriteLine(TrnAmount.ToString("C3", myUSCulture)); // exactly 3 digits after .
  Console.WriteLine(TrnAmount.ToString("C2", myUSCulture)); 
  Console.WriteLine(TrnAmount.ToString("C0", myUSCulture)); // no floating point
```

**Outcome:**

```
  -123,456,789.987
  -123,456,789.99  // rounded
  -123,456,790     // rounded
```